# Store big structure in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, memory, structure

I am fitting a statistical model in matlab using fitglm which returns a structure mdl. I would like to store many such structures in an array of cells to reuse them later but this seems not to work. Here is the code:

```
models = cell(size(quarterList,1)-lag-1,1);

for i=1:size(quarterList,1)-lag-1
    %indicesTemp = find(and(annQuarters(:,2) <= quarterList(i+11,2),annQuarters(:,2) >= quarterList(i,2)));
    memberTemp = ismember(annQuarters(:,:), quarterList(i:i+lag,:));
    indicesTemp = find(memberTemp(:,2));
    fprintf('Perdiod: Q%i %i to Q%i %i - Nb samples: %i \n',annQuarters(i,1),annQuarters(i,2),annQuarters(i+lag,1),annQuarters(i+lag,2),size(indicesTemp,1));

    [Xtemp Ytemp] = categorizeVariables(X(indicesTemp,:),Y(indicesTemp,:));

    mdl = fitglm(Xtemp,Ytemp-1,'Distribution','binomial', 'Link','logit');

    models(i,1) = mdl;     
end
```

Now when I try to assign such structure to a single cell, it works:

```
temp = cell(1,1);
mdl = fitglm(Xtemp,Ytemp-1,'Distribution','binomial', 'Link','logit');
temp = mdl;
```

Why is the assignment in the array of cells not working in that case? Any suggestion on how to go around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't work because using `models(index)` assignment (with `()`) assumes that the thing on the right side *is a cell*. You instead want to use curly brackets which will copy the item on the right (of any type) *into* the cell array at the specified element.

```
models{i,1} = mdl;
```

If you really wanted to use `()`, you could instead *convert* the thing on the right to a cell first.

```
models(i,1) = {mdl};
```

The reason that your second example (with a scalar cell array) doesn't result in an error is because you *aren't* putting the output of `fitglm` into the cell array but rather *overwriting* the variable `temp` to point to `mdl` instead of the cell array.

```
temp = cell(1,1);

% Check if temp is a cell
iscell(temp)
%// TRUE

mdl = fitglm(Xtemp,Ytemp-1,'Distribution','binomial','Link','logit');

temp = mdl;

% Check if temp is still a cell (it isn't)
iscell(temp)
%// FALSE
```

All of that aside, you can actually store `struct`s within an array themselves. You don't actually need a cell array unless the fields are different.

```
for i = 1:N
    mdl(i) = fitglm(Xtemp, Ytemp - 1, 'Distribution', 'binomial', 'Link', 'logit'); 
end
```